Regular expression for google form to check if a string entered by the user exist or not
Regular expression pattern for a google form to check if a string entered by the user exist or not.
So I want to prepopulate the field with some data like email addresses of some selected users and once the user provide his email I will check if it with the prepopulated email address to see if it exist or not.
In google form not for any other languages.
Thank you.

Select Regex with a "Doesn't contain".
For the regex, you just take all the emails and delimit them with a "|".
That means "or".
You'll also want to escape any dots in your emails. That's a special character that means "any character".
So to block these emails "one@gmail.com" and "john.doe@gmail.com"
You would enter this regex
one@gmail\.com|john\.doe@gmail.com
Here's an example/playground for testing.
https://regex101.com/r/G4I1G6/1


Thank you, but I want to allow only these emails. For example I want these emails to be allowed "one@gmail.com" and "john.doe@gmail.com"

Then in the Google Form, change "Doesn't contain" to "Contains".
